# When to use Shell#getToolBar() instead of new ToolBar()

Tags: java, swt

According to the SWT documentation for [Shell#getToolBar()](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FShell.html&anchor=getToolBar()):

> Returns a ToolBar object representing the tool bar that can be shown in the receiver's trim. This will return null if the platform does not support tool bars that are not part of the content area of the shell, or if the Shell's style does not support having a tool bar.

Under what OSes (Windows, Mac, or Linux) or circumstances would this return null instead of a toolbar? Is this an antiquated feature? All of the examples that I've found ignore the existence of this method and opt to create a new ToolBar instance instead.

Side question: What exactly is the "receiver's trim" and "content area of the shell"? Are normal toolbars not considered part of the shell's content area?

Comment: The _receiver's trim_ is the area outside of the client area, for example, the border and caption bar. The _content area_ is the rectangle returned by `getClientArea()` All child controls are located here, i.e. the ones you create like  `new Button( shell, SWT.PUSH )`. My guess is that `getToolBar()` is used to represent the tool bar right below the system-wide menu bar on systems that support this style.

Comment: Given that this method was added in a rather recent version (3.7) my guess is that it is not an _antiquated_ feature